# TypeScript & React: compose higher-order components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, higher-order-components, function-composition

I'm new to TypeScript with React and I have (already) two HOCs in React and I would like to `compose` them because it is likely that there will be more.

```
import { getIsAuthenticated } from 'features/user-authentication/user-authentication-reducer';
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState } from 'redux/root-reducer';

import { withTranslation } from '../../../i18n';
import HomePageComponent from './home-page-component';

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
  isAuthenticated: getIsAuthenticated(state),
});

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps);

export type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

export default withTranslation()(connector(HomePageComponent));
```

That is how it currently looks (and works / compiles). The component is:

```
// ...
import { TFunction } from 'next-i18next';
// ...
import { PropsFromRedux } from './home-page-container';

type Props = {
  readonly t: TFunction;
} & PropsFromRedux;

const HomePageComponent = ({ isAuthenticated, t }: Props) => (
// ...
```

In JavaScript I usually do:

```js
export default compose(withTranslation(), connector)(HomePageComponent);
```

where `compose` is either from Ramda or from Redux itself.

Using Ramda's `compose` throws two errors.

1. `connector`: `No overload matches this call.`
2. `HomePageComponent`: `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.`

Using Redux' `compose` compiles here, but breaks my tests.

```
import { render, screen } from 'tests/test-helpers';

import HomePageContainer from './home-page-container';

describe('Home Page Container', () => {
  it('should render a greeting', () => {
    render(<HomePageContainer />);

    expect(screen.getByText(/hello world/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

In the test file, `HomePageContainer` throws:

```
JSX element type 'HomePageContainer' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

How can I use `compose` for higher-order components and get it to work with TypeScript?

**PS:** I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65167644/typescript-react-compose-higher-order-components) other question and answer in SO, but the answer doesn't work in the latest TS versions and its only for two HOCs, I need to compose more.

My `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

Minimal example in CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hoc-breaking-example-mtp3m

Comment: could you provide a minimal example in codesandbox or github repo?

Comment: @diedu Done, I updated the question. Make sure to wait for CodeSandbox to load (takes a bit) and then checkout `App.test.tsx`. It throws `JSX element type 'App' does not have any construct or call signatures.`, too. And In `App.tsx` you can play around with the `compose` version (what's broken and I'm trying to achieve) and the consecutive application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to rambda `compose` typing you'll see that it's generic, so you can define what would be the resulting function, typing it like this removes the error

```
export default compose<React.FunctionComponent>(
  withTitle("Hello StackOverflow!"),
  connector
)(App);
```